# Hide thumbnail if there is a gallery on the post

Tags: posts, images

In a post I want to always show one of two options-

If the post has nothing but a thumbnail image show the thumbnail.

If the post has **both** the thumbnail and a gallery then show the only gallery and don't show the thumbnail.

I am using a plugin for the gallery called [metaslider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/).

but I don't know what the php would be to wrap these two options in?

```
        <p class="post-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></p>
        <p class="post-gallery"><?php the_field('post_gallery'); ?></p>
```

Comment: Did you try the [`has_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) function ?

Comment: Keep in mind what is off topic here: [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

Just use the public API functions: [`has_shortcode( $content, $tag );`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L157-L176). It uses [`shortcode_exists( $shortcode );`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L143) internally to search the `global $shortcode_tags` array for the shortcode you are searching for. If that is successful, it uses [`get_shortcode_regex()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L228-L264) to search for the actual shortcode - this will save you quite some time and avoid mistakes.

```
the_title();
if ( has_shortcode( get_the_content(), 'gallery' ) )
{
    the_content();
}
else 
{
    // show default view - example:
    the_post_thumbnail( 'your-desired-size' );
    the_content();
}
```

The [`gallery_shortcode( $post_id );`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/media.php#L906-L1098) function might be of help as well.
This might not work if you are using a plugin that handles galleries different from how WP core does it. Anyway, make sure that you alter above `has_shortcode()` call to use the shortcode you are (or the plugin you are using) is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do preg_match to check if the content contains gallery shortcode

```
    <?php 
         $re = "/\\[metaslider id=([0-9]+).*]/s"; 
         if(preg_match($re, get_the_content(), $matches) && has_post_thumbnail()){
             ?>
             <p class="post-gallery"><?php the_field('post_gallery'); ?></p>
             <?php
         }else{
             ?>
             <p class="post-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></p>
             <?php
         }
     ?>
```

The above code checks if the content has the shortcode [gallery] present and also if it has post thumbnail. If it does then it executes the 1st block else it executes the 2nd block

Comment: Thanks Karun, I tried the above but it got rid of the gallery and only showed the thumbnail when the gallery was present?

Comment: Sorry I should have also said that I'm using a plugin for the gallery and the short code for that is like `[metaslider id=1017]`

Comment: I've edited my code. You can test now

Comment: Thanks but still only showing the thumbnail?

Comment: I've tested my code with that plugin you are using. I added a gallery plus added a featured thumbnail and ran it. The result was as expected.

Comment: did you use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin as well?

Comment: No, in that case may be in the preg_match, the "get_the_content()" should be replaced by the field itself. By default the main editor is used I assumed that slider would be used there. Please edit the preg match parameters if required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19508/discussion-between-karun-and-nsokyi).